# How to clear a list from a function VB.NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, function, variables

I want to be able to clear a list from a function.
When I try to clear the list from a separate function, it won't find the list.
 If you want to see my full code I'm working on then it's here: https://pastebin.com/jrLiNZKd

```
Module Module1

    Structure Person
        Dim Name As String
        Dim DoB As Date
    End Structure
    Dim sFileName As String = "Z:/" ' the name and file path of the saved file

    Public Sub Main()
        Dim localDir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
        localDir = localDir & "/People.txt"
        sFileName = localDir
        Dim tempDir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile) & "/temp.tmp"
        ' create a new list to store our structure data type 'Person'
        Dim lstPeople As New List(Of Person)
        Dim chMenuOpt As Char
        Do
            DisplayMenu() ' call sub and display menu options
            Console.WriteLine("There are currently " & lstPeople.Count & " people entered.")

            chMenuOpt = Console.ReadKey.KeyChar ' get keyboard character and store in chMenuOpt

            Select Case chMenuOpt
                Case "1"
                    lstPeople.AddRange(GetPeople) ' get more people and add to lstPeople
                Case "6"
                    Exit Do
                Case "7"

                    IO.File.Create(tempDir).Dispose()

                    Dim s As New IO.StreamWriter(tempDir, True)
                    s.WriteLine(lstPeople.Count)
                    s.Close()
                    lstPeople.AddRange(TestCrapThing)
                Case "8"
                    MakeFile()
                Case "0"
                    'lstPeople.Clear()
                    CLearPeople(lstPeople)
            End Select
        Loop
        ' user chose to exit program
    End Sub
    Sub CLearPeople(lst As List(Of Person))
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("All loaded people have been cleared!")
        lst.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Sub MakeFile()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Do you really want to continue [Yes/No]")
        Dim innnn As Char = Console.ReadKey.KeyChar
        If LCase(innnn) = "y" Then
            Console.Clear()
            IO.File.Create(sFileName).Dispose()
            Console.WriteLine("The file renewed!")
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ")
            Console.ReadKey()
        Else

        End If
    End Sub
    Sub DisplayMenu()
        Console.Clear()
        Console.WriteLine("Please pick an option. There are loads to choose from xD")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("1) Add people")
        Console.WriteLine("6) Quit")
        Console.WriteLine("7) Load from file")
        Console.WriteLine("8) Make file / Clear file")
        Console.WriteLine("0) Unload people")
        Console.WriteLine()
    End Sub

    Function TestCrapThing() As List(Of Person)
        Console.Clear()
        Dim count As Decimal = 0
        Dim d As New IO.StreamReader(sFileName, True)
        Do Until d.EndOfStream = True
            d.ReadLine()
            count = count + 1
        Loop
        d.Close()
        Console.Clear()
        Dim s As New IO.StreamReader(sFileName, True)
        ' builds a list of people from the user.  The user types "Stop" to end the list
        ' when function ends, the list is returned

        Dim tmpPerson As Person ' Used while entering data, added at end
        Dim tmpDate As String ' stores user's DOB.  This can be checked to see if valid, before storing
        Dim tmpPeopleList As New List(Of Person) ' store added names in temporary list
        Console.Clear()
        ' the loop goes around an infinite number of times.  Only exits when user types 'Stop'
        Console.WriteLine("In progress...")
        Console.WriteLine("There are " & count & " lines.")
        Console.WriteLine("")
        Do Until s.EndOfStream = True
            ' ############
            ' # Get Name #
            ' ############
            Dim countt As Decimal = 0
            Dim tempstuff As String = s.ReadLine
            Dim tempsplit As String() = tempstuff.Split(New Char() {"|"})
            Dim part As String = tempsplit(1)
            For Each part In tempsplit
                countt = countt + 1
                tmpPerson.Name = tempsplit(0)
                tmpPerson.DoB = CDate(tempsplit(1))
                If countt = 2 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Added: " & tempsplit(0))
                    Console.WriteLine("with date of: " & tempsplit(1))
                    tmpPeopleList.Add(tmpPerson)
                    countt = 0
                End If
            Next
        Loop ' loop back around to get next person
        Dim localDir As String = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
        Dim tmp As New IO.StreamReader(localDir & "/temp.tmp", True)
        If tmp.ReadLine = "0" Then ' If no people are loaded then it won't ask to clear it.
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.WriteLine("Imported new people!")
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ")
            Console.ReadKey()
            tmp.Close()
            s.Close()
            Return tmpPeopleList
        Else
            Console.WriteLine("")
            Console.WriteLine("Do you want to clear all the existing people loaded into the program? [Yes/No]")
            Dim inputty As Char = Console.ReadKey.KeyChar
            If inputty = "y" Then
                'need finish !!!!!!!!!!!!THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CLEAR THE LIST !!!!!!
                Return tmpPeopleList ' send temporary list back for processing
                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.WriteLine("Cleared people and imported new people!")
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ")
            Else
                tmp.Close()
                s.Close()
                Return tmpPeopleList ' send temporary list back for processing
                Console.WriteLine("")
                Console.WriteLine("imported new people!")
                Console.WriteLine("Press any key to continue . . . ")
            End If
        End If
        Console.ReadKey()
        tmp.Close()
        s.Close()
    End Function
    Function GetPeople() As List(Of Person)
        ' builds a list of people from the user.  The user types "Stop" to end the list
        ' when function ends, the list is returned

        Dim tmpPerson As Person ' Used while entering data, added at end
        Dim tmpDate As String ' stores user's DOB.  This can be checked to see if valid, before storing
        Dim tmpPeopleList As New List(Of Person) ' store added names in temporary list
        Console.Clear()
        ' the loop goes around an infinite number of times.  Only exits when user types 'Stop'
        Do
            ' ############
            ' # Get Name #
            ' ############
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the person's name.  Type 'Stop' or 'Quit' to finish entering names.")
            tmpPerson.Name = Console.ReadLine ' get name
            If LCase(tmpPerson.Name) = "stop" Or LCase(tmpPerson.Name) = "quit" Then
                Exit Do ' immediately exit, do not add to the list
            End If

            ' ###########
            ' # Get DOB #
            ' ###########
            Do ' loop infinitely until user gives a valid date.
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter " & tmpPerson.Name & "'s DOB.")
                tmpDate = Console.ReadLine ' read into temporary string to validate date

                If IsDate(tmpDate) = False Then ' user entered an invalid date
                    Console.WriteLine("Sorry, that was an invalid date.  Please try again.")
                Else
                    tmpPerson.DoB = CDate(tmpDate) ' convert to a date and store
                    Exit Do ' quit infinite loop as we have a valid date
                End If
            Loop

            tmpPeopleList.Add(tmpPerson) ' remember, a function becomes the return value.
        Loop ' loop back around to get next person
        Return tmpPeopleList ' send temporary list back for processing
    End Function
End Module
```

Comment: what does `it won't find the list` mean?  It doesnt look like you are calling that clear method

Comment: well I want to find a way to clear the list from the function. It will say it's not declared

Comment: @Simas which line does it say it is not declared?

Comment: well if you try to add something like: lstPeople.Clear then it will say that.

Comment: You already have a function that does that, CLearPeople

Comment: Yes but I want to be able to clear it in the function. Thats what my school worksheet says.

Comment: Note that since `lstPeople` is a local variable (instead of an instance variable), you need to pass it as a parameter if you want to use it in a different function. That's why `ClearPeople(lstPeople)` would work, it takes in the list as a parameter and clears it.

Comment: So is there any way I could clear it from the function? Maybe changing the variable type or something

Comment: If you want to pass a `List` and access its members, it has to be passed 'ByRef', otherwise you are accessing a copy of that list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. assuming that you want to clear `lstPeople` from with the called function(pretty bad practice tbh), you need to change a few things.

OK - you need to pass a reference to `lstPeople` to your function.. change the function declaration to ..

```
Function TestCrapThing(ByRef originalList As List(Of Person)) As List(Of Person)
```

Further back up your code, you can now call the function using ..

```
lstPeople.AddRange(TestCrapThing(lstPeople))
```

This means that when you call `TestCrapThing` with the parameter `lstPeople`, you pass a reference to the function. In the function this is referred to using `originalList`.

So.. at your comment line ..

```
'need finish !!!!!!!!!!!!THIS IS WHERE I WANT TO CLEAR THE LIST !!!!!!
```

add this line

```
    originalList.Clear()
```

which will clear the list that it refers to - `lstPeople` on this occasion.

Viola